# mysqli prepared statement update query fails when id is cast as integer but not as string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

In the below code, I am attempting to take three form variables ($nps,$sch,$joint) and an id ($weld_id) and insert them into an UPDATE query. The problem is that I get $stmt->error "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement."

When I cast the id of the row as "i". The weird thing is that the statement will execute error free if I put single quotes around the last question mark and cast as 's', however, the actual database row will not update. The function on row 3 does NOT use prepared statements to select the current values for this row in the database.

I have var_dumped all variables, copied them and successfuly run the query on MySQL workbench. I am out of ideas, please help.

```
$weld = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['id']);
$weld = single_weld_query($db,$weld);
if(isset($_POST['edit_weld_parameters'])){
    // Query to update 3 parameters on database entry where id = N
    $stmt       = $db->prepare("UPDATE `welds` SET `size` = '?' , `sch` = '?' , `joint` = '?' WHERE `id` = ?;");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $nps, $sch, $joint, $weld_id);
    $nps        = isset($_POST['size'])?    mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['size']):          $weld['size'];
    $sch        = isset($_POST['sch'])?     mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['sch']):           $weld['sch'];
    $joint  = isset($_POST['joint'])?   mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['joint']):         $weld['joint'];
    $nps        = (strlen($nps) and in_array($nps,$pipe_obj->sizes))?                       $nps:   $weld['size'];
    $sch        = (strlen($sch) and in_array($sch,$pipe_obj->schedules))?                   $sch:   $weld['sch'];
    $joint  = (strlen($joint) and in_array(strtoupper($joint),$pipe_obj->joint_types))? $joint: $weld['joint'];
    $weld_id    = $weld['id'];
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo $weld['weld_number'].' parameters edited.';
    }else{
        echo $stmt->error;
    }
}else{
    echo 'ERROR: Form failure.';
}
```

Comment: what is **sssi** in  $stmt->bind_param("sssi".. ?

Answer (score 1):

You're using prepared statements with placeholder values, which is great, but you're also escaping things, which is bad. That ends up double-escaping them. Leave the escaping up to the driver, use placeholder values, and you'll be fine:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_weld_parameters'])) {
    // Query to update 3 parameters on database entry where id = N
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `welds` SET `size` = ? , `sch` = ? , `joint` = ? WHERE `id` = ?;");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssi",
       isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : $weld['size'],
       isset($_POST['sch']) ? $_POST['sch'] : $weld['sch'],
       isset($_POST['joint'])?   $db,$_POST['joint'] : $weld['joint'],
       $weld['id']
    );

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo $weld['weld_number'].' parameters edited.';
    }
    else {
        echo $stmt->error;
    }
}
else {
    echo 'ERROR: Form failure.';
}
```

There's other code you'll need to wrangle in there, you're doing some very odd things to validate those after the fact, but try and stick with this general pattern.

Let the driver do the work. Do not put `'?'` in your query. Do not inline strings with interpolation. Don't escape anything that's already a placeholder value. Do try and keep your logic clean and obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, sorry, new to prepared statements... I tried my code but without '?' and that worked too. So, why is escaping bad? I am updating some old code without removing the mysqli_real_escape_str()'s. Is that a major issue?

Comment: Manual escaping is bad because you might forget and not notice. With prepared statements you'll get an error you can't ignore if you're not matching things up right. That's the difference between failing and opening up a SQL injection hole and failing safely.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help.